# Is there a way of adding a windows type progress bar to a powershell script running Dism?

Tags: powershell, progress-bar, dism

I am trying to add a windows type progress bar to a powershell script running Dism. I am having difficulty with thw win32_service. Would anyone know how to do this?

dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:Z:\path\wim.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:C:\

Comment: What does `dism` have to do with `win32_service`?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick reply. I am trying to use the below script.                $wmiQuery = “Select name from win32_service where state = ‘running'”
$colItems = Get-WmiObject -Query $wmiQuery
For($i = 1; $i -le $colItems.count; $i++)
{ Write-Progress -Activity “Gathering Services” -status “Found Service $i” `
-percentComplete ($i / $colItems.count*100)}
$colItems | Select name

Comment: It's better for you to update your question than place this code in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Mathias R. Jessen point.

Making and using PowerShell progress bar(s) is a well documented thing in the PowerShell built-in help files and all over the web. Here is a goo article with several examples regarding ['How to Make a PowerShell Progress Bar'](https://thinkpowershell.com/how-to-make-a-powershell-progress-bar/)

The author provides and shows via gifs of single

```
For ($i=0; $i -le 100; $i++) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 20
    Write-Progress -Activity "Counting to 100" -Status "Current Count: $i" -PercentComplete $i -CurrentOperation "Counting ..."
}
```

and nested progress bars.

```
For ($i=0; $i -le 100; $i++) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1
    Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "First Write Progress" -Status "Current Count: $i" -PercentComplete $i -CurrentOperation "Counting ..."

    For ($j=0; $j -le 100; $j++) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1
        Write-Progress -Id 2 -Activity "Second Write Progress" -Status "Current Count: $j" -PercentComplete $j -CurrentOperation "Counting ..."
    }
}
```

Also, any reason you are using WQL vs the built-in PowerShell cmdlets for looking at services?

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}
```

As well as why you'd want a progress bar for that, since the return s immediate, and the outputting just the name? Which you can just do ...

```
(Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}).Name
```

or

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select-Object -Property Name
```

Each will have a return that is very fast, that a progress bar is moot unless you intentionally slow it down with the Start-Sleep cmdlet, but there should be little reason for that.

If you are looking for a script with a progress bar for DISM. See this discussion and pre-built sample here:

[Generate a GUI progress bar for DISM or ImageX](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/815c880b-0338-40df-abb0-021cfeda288d/generate-a-gui-progress-bar-for-dism-or-images)

The accepted answer provided is a long block of code, that is too long to post here: